# Cannot set tags for some views

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, nsview

In Xcode 5/6 the **tag** field is disabled for a number of views, enabled for others.

I couldn't find any explanation or related questions to this behavior -
why are things like scroll views or clip views not taggable from Interface builder in Xcode?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot and some context? To be honest, tagging is usually not a great way to identify views, imho, but I suppose it  exists for a reason.

Comment: @Moshe Agreed. In this particular case I need to access dozens of views sprinkled across the view hierarchy of the window assembled from dozens of `.xibs`, though.

Comment: That sounds precarious!

Comment: @Moshe ..just a wee bit ;-) It's actually about sprinkling *Pages*-like help bubbles across my UI from a centralized helper class. For the task in question it seemed a light-weight and apt approach

Comment: Really? This sounds like a popover sort of thing. If you're on iPhone, I'm sure there's a better way to do it than this. Now you have me wanting to write a framework for this, but I bet it exists.

Comment: @Moshe Open to suggestions :-) As usual, time was running out and help the last thing to implement before the MAS go-life.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting tags is actually only defined for `NSControl` and derived objects -

**NSControl Class Reference:**
[Getting and Setting Tags](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000073-SW17)

The Xcode UI is a bit confusing as it appears to allow setting tags for arbitrary views.
A vanilla view doesn't allow to set tags, only provides a read-only accessor.